# How can a Python class refer to one of its subclasses, or an instance thereof?

Tags: python

Is it possible for the `__new__` method of a Python class `A` to refer to a (constant) instance of a *subclass* of `A`?

To illustrate (motivate?) this question, below is a toy implementation of Lisp-like lists in Perl.  A Lisp list is often defined *recursively* as a pair (aka `cons`) whose first element is some arbitrary Lisp object and whose second element is a list.  To avoid an infinite recursion, Lisp has a sentinel constant called `nil` that is *defined* to be a list.  Therefore, `nil` is a list, `(cons 3 nil)` is a list, `(cons 3 (cons 1 nil))` is a list, etc. (although the last two examples are more commonly written as `(3)` and `(3 1)`, respectively).

The Perl implementation of this definition that I give below construes `nil` as being an instance of a subclass of `list`.  Nevertheless, the definition of the `list` class refers to this `nil` constant.

```
# list.pm
use strict;
BEGIN {
  sub list::nil ();
}

package _nil;
{
  my $nil = bless \ do { my $x }, '_nil';
  sub nil () { $nil; }
}
*car = *cdr = sub { shift };
our @ISA = ( 'list' );

package list;
*nil = *_nil::nil;
sub new {
  my $cls = shift;
  @_ ? bless [ shift, $cls->new( @_ ) ], $cls : nil;
}
sub car () { shift->[ 0 ] }
sub cdr () { shift->[ 1 ] }
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw( list nil );
1;
```

```
% perl -Mlist -e 'printf "nil->isa(\047list\047) = %s\n", \
                  nil->isa(q(list)) ? q(t) : q(f)'
nil->isa('list') = t
```

(`car` and `cdr` are Lisp-ish for the first and second element of the `cons` object.)

The point of the example is to show that, in Perl (even my outdated Perl, at a well-below-expert level), it is trivial to implement a class that refers to an instance of a subclass.  This is because, in Perl, a class `B` can be declared a subclass of `A` even before `A` has been defined.  (This is what the line

```
our @ISA = ( 'list' );
```

does.)

I'm looking for some way to approximate this effect in Python.

EDIT/clarification:

Among the many things I've tried, here's one that hits close to the mark.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import chain

class List(namedtuple('pair', 'car cdr')):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            return super(List, cls).__new__(cls, args[0], cls(*args[1:]))
        else:
            return nil
    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s)' % ' '.join(map(str, self))
    def __iter__(self):
        return chain((self.car,), iter(self.cdr))

class Nil(object):
    car = cdr = property(lambda s: s)
    __str__ = lambda s: 'nil'
    def __iter__(self):
        if False: yield

nil = Nil()

print List(3, 4, 5)
print nil, nil.car, nil.cdr
print 'isinstance(nil, List) -> %s' % isinstance(nil, List)
```

The output is:

```
(3 4 5)
nil nil nil
isinstance(nil, List) -> False
```

...which is fine, except for the last line.

If one changes the definition of `Nil` to start with `class Nil(List)` instead, then one gets the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 38, in <module>
    nil = Nil()
  File "list.py", line 25, in __new__
    return nil
NameError: global name 'nil' is not defined
```

Comment: I know nothing about Perl, but it should work just fine in Python. What did you attempt and how did it fail?

Comment: @delnan: it's hard to answer your question because I've tried so many ways to do this in Python, and all of them failed.  With Perl, I can define an arbitrary object (one that starts out having no class), and then, after it already exists, I can *assign* to it *any* class, whether this class has been defined or not.  Similarly, in Perl, I can specify the parent-child relationship between classes pretty much at any point in the code, irrespective of the code that defines the individual classes.  In Python, if I write `x = B()`, the class `B` better well be defined by this point in the code...

Comment: ...and similarly, if I write `class B(A):`, `A` better well be defined by this point in the code!

Comment: It'd still probably be more helpful if you gave us a code sample with non-working Python instead of Perl. (Nothing against Perl but its approach to OO is idiosyncratic enough that it's nontrivial to read for people not used to it, as opposed to procedural code in it.)

Comment: @millimoose: I've added some Python code sample to my question

Comment: @delnan: I've added some Python code sample to my question

Comment: @kjo Lateral suggestion: use interfaces or [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) if all you need is the `isinstance()` check to pass. I.e. if `Nil` doesn't really inherit any useful *behaviour* from `List`. Having `Nil` inherit from `List` seems like odd OO design. And even if you do want the classes to share behaviour, you can do so using multiple inheritance by having both inherit a third "mixin" class.

Comment: Also `__str__ = lambda s: 'nil'` makes my spine shiver a little. It's not exactly wrong but it seems out of place.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I've been exposed to Perl, but is it what you're doing in your code? `car` and `cdr` of `nil` are supposed to return itself, right?

```
class List:

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            return cls(args[0], cls.new(*args[1:]))
        else:
            return nil

    def __init__(self, head, tail):
        self.head = head
        self.tail = tail

    def car(self):
        return self.head

    def cdr(self):
        return self.tail


class Nil(List):

    def __init__(self):
        List.__init__(self, None, None)

    def car(self):
        return self

    def cdr(self):
        return self


nil = Nil()


print(isinstance(nil, List))
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're really asking is: if declaring the subclass requires the base class to exist, but the implementation of the base class requires the subclass, how can this be resolved?

The answer to this lies in the following factors:

- Python classes are values, stored in variables.
- You can change what value a variable refers to at runtime.
- The body of the `__new__` block is not evaluated until you call it.

Therefore you can declare your base class first, with its constructor referring to the subclass, and then subsequently put the subclass in place before anyone gets a chance to run the constructor. For example:

```
Sub = None
sub_instance = None

class Base(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        # you can do something with Sub or sub_instance in here,
        # because this won't be executed until the following
        # class decl and instantiation have been evaluated.
        pass

class Sub(Base):
    def __new__(cls):
       # Override __new__ in the subclass so that the base class
       # constructor won't run for this subclass.
       # By calling the object constructor directly we can build a type
       # "manually" without running Base.__new__.
       return object.__new__(Sub)
    def __init__(self):
       pass

sub_instance = Sub()

# You can safely do the following at any point after you've
# defined Sub and sub_instance. Before that, it'll fail
# because Sub and sub_instance are still None.
base_instance = Base()
```

Python just treats the global scope as a dictionary, so as long as the right values are in it by the time you access it the intended behavior will occur. Since a class is just a value of type `type`, you can change what's assigned to the `Sub` variable at any time during your program, and since Python is dynamically typed you can even change it from one type to another if you want.

The main challenge here is in instantiating the subclass without evaluating the base class constructor. One way to do this is to mask the base class constructor with a special implementation in the subclass, as I showed in my example above. In this overridden implementation you will need to preserve any invariants the base class expects without calling into the base class constructor itself. Another solution is to just design the base class constructor to be tolerant of sub_instance being `None` during the initial setup.

Comment: I don't think this works because when `sub_instance` is constructed by the call to `Sub()` which implicitly calls `Base.__new__()` it will refer to the then current value of `sub_instance` -- `None` -- at that point.

Comment: A fair point martineau... some additional care is required to allow the Sub() constructor to run to completion even though the Base constructor is not complete yet. I'll add some more to my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, why are you creating a *type* in `__new__`? None of your classes are metaclasses. `Sub.__new__` should return a `Sub` instance, perhaps through `object.__new__`.

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` as any other function can refer to any object bound to some name in its scope via this name.

Example implementation:

```
class Cons:
    def __new__(cls, car, cdr):
        if cdr is None and car is None:
            return cls.NIL  # __init__ is called unnecessarily 
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, car, cdr):
        self.car = car
        self.cdr = cdr

    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
        it = iter(iterable)
        try:
            car = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            return cls.NIL
        else:
            return cls(car, cls.from_iterable(it))

    def __iter__(self):
        if self is not self.NIL:
            yield self.car
            yield from self.cdr

    def _repr(self):
        if self is self.NIL:
            return "NIL"
        else:
            return "({} . {})".format(self.car, self.cdr._repr())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{} {}>".format(self.__class__.__name__, self._repr()) 

Cons.NIL = NIL = super(Cons, Cons).__new__(Cons)
NIL.car = NIL
NIL.cdr = NIL
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the simplest way of achieving what you want is this:

```
from itertools import chain

class List(object):

    def __init__(self, car=None, *args):
        self.car = car
        if args:
            self.cdr = List(*args)
        else:
            self.cdr = ()

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s)' % ' '.join(map(str, iter(self)))

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.car:
            return iter(())
        return chain((self.car,), iter(self.cdr))


nil = List()

print List(3, 4, 5)
print nil, nil.car, nil.cdr
print 'isinstance(nil, List) -> %s' % isinstance(nil, List)
```

Result:

```
(3 4 5)
() None ()
isinstance(nil, List) -> True
```

It's very different from your code, but as far as I can tell it does pretty much the same (except that it doesn't print out the text string 'nil' instead of empty values, but uses the typical Python empty values in that case. This can be easily changed).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution.  In the code I provided at the end of the question, have `Nil` inherit from both `List` and `tuple`, and give it a `__new__` method, as shown below:

```
class Nil(List, tuple):
    def __new__(cls):
        return globals().setdefault('nil', tuple.__new__(cls))

    # rest of definition unchanged
```

Now the output is

```
(3 4 5)
nil nil nil
True
```